# Qual a origem do nome "brevidade" para designar um bolinho feito de polvilho?

Tags: etimologia, definição

No Brasil, especialmente no Sudeste, há um bolinho normalmente feito de polvilho, que nossas avós chamavam de **brevidade**. Exemplo: [Receita do bolinho brevidade](http://www.cybercook.com.br/receita-de-brevidade-r-7-18815.html)

Notei que o dicionário [priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/brevidade) não cita essa definição, mas outros dicionários como o [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=brevidade) e [outros](https://www.dicio.com.br/brevidade/), citam.

Por que este bolinho é chamado de **brevidade** ? É exclusivo do Brasil ?

Comment: Onde será que encontro a receita original

Comment: @Raquel: Boa pergunta, minha vó fazia. Mas você ainda o encontra com facilidade no estado de MG, versão industrializada, porém.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diz o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) que segundo o filólogo brasileiro [Antenor Nacentes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenor_Nascentes) o nome do bolo se deve à sua rapidez de preparação (desabreviando):

> **Brevidade** [...] **4** CULINÁRIA *Brasil Baía São Paulo Centro-Oeste do Brasil* espécie de bolinho quebradiço, leve e farinhento, feito de polvilho (ou araruta ou maisena) e ovos, açúcar etc. ʘ ETIMOLOGIA latim *brevitas, atis* [...] Nascentes observa que o nome do bolinho (acepção 4) está relacionado com a rapidez com que é preparado;

Aqui em Portugal nunca ouvi falar de um bolo com esse nome. Entretanto procurei no Google Books, e um bolinho chamado *brevidade* já aparece mencionado em [1872 em *Inocência* de Alfredo d’Escragnolle Taunay, sob o nome de pluma Sylvio Dinarte](http://www.brasiliana.usp.br/bitstream/handle/1918/01896200/018962_COMPLETO.pdf) (p. 246, grafia e itálico original):

> Quero que dez dias ante da *fonçonata* venha a comadre do Ricardo com seu povo para preparar os sequilhos, tarecos, biscoutos de polvilho e *brevidades*. (1)
>
> […]
>
> [Nota de rodapé] (1) *Brevidade* é uma especie de pão de milho em que entra clara de ovo.

É interessante que o autor sentiu necessidade de explicar o que era a *brevidade*, o que sugere que o nome era pouco conhecido na altura. No seu livro [*Ao entardecer*](http://www.brasiliana.usp.br/bitstream/handle/1918/01896200/018962_COMPLETO.pdf), em 1901 (ou melhor, antes da sua morte em 1899) voltou a referir *brevidades*, três vezes, mas já não explicou o que eram.